# Making background on a page that scrolls and stops and is centered

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a web page that is centered. I need to make background (for the background ad) that way that it would be scrolling until it reaches the bottom and then if would get fixed.

I tried using this css code:

```
#adContainer{position:absolute;top:0px;left:50%}
#ad {z-index:1;position:relative;left:-50%;}
```

My HTML is:

```
<div id="adContainer">
   <div id="ad">
   </div>
</div>
```

And my javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bottomPos = $('#adContainer').outerHeight(true) - $(window).height();
    $(window).scroll( function() {
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() > bottomPos) {
            $('#adContainer').css({'position':'fixed','top':'auto','bottom':'0px'});
        } else {
            $('#adContainer').css({'position':'absolute','top':'0px'});
        }
    });
});
```

My ad is bigger than the visible space (wider and deeper).

Everything works... except I get horizontal scroolbars in every browser ;-( I can not get rid of them (overflow:none) nor do I know why they appear.

How can I achieve my goal without the horizontal scrollbars?

Here is the jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xo9d4n0e/

Why does the horizontal scrollbar extend beyond the black line, which indicates the end of my image (there is no image in jsfiddle, it is the black line only).

Comment: Try using overflow-x: hidden on your body. However, if this does not work, we will need a jsFiddle or something more to help you. Without an image and some content, we can't help much.

Comment: Can I add image to jsFiddle? I'll try to make example. Overflow-x on body works, but if the screen is narrower than the content of the page of course there is no horizontal slider either, that is not good.